# When can I not replace a random variable with its mean?

Tags: modeling, mean, random-variable

A frequent simplification in modeling and simulation is to replace a random variable by its mean value.

When would this simplification lead to the wrong conclusion?

Comment: Does "Var" stand for *variable* or *variance* or *Value At Risk*?

Comment: It'd be fun to start a service that pays for its members' Netflix subscription.  We'd charge only $\left|x\right|~\frac{\mathrm{USD}}{\mathrm{month}}$, where $x$ is randomly selected in the domain $\left[-100,100\right]$, so, ya know, free Netflix!  Later, we'll offer some customers the option to instead pay $x^2~\frac{\mathrm{USD}}{\mathrm{month}}$.

Comment: Well in a very simple case if we take it to the the extreme we could lose pretty much all the information we care about.  Consider a regression of Y on X where we replaced both Y and X with their mean.  Any information about the slope is now lost.

Comment: Are you asking about replacing missing values, or are you asking about a replacing a random variable in a specific context (e.g. making predictions base on a random-effects model)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you replace a missing value by some point estimate, you disregard all its variability. Thus, you will not propagate all the original variability to your model. Your parameter estimates will appear to have too low [standard-error](/questions/tagged/standard-error)s. If you do inference, your p values will be biased low. Your [confidence-interval](/questions/tagged/confidence-interval)s will be too narrow. If you do prediction, your [prediction-interval](/questions/tagged/prediction-interval)s will be too narrow.

Overall: you will be too sure of your conclusions.

Comment: Good answer! Think about this way: A random variable has a distribution. It can be skweded to the left, to the right. I can be bi-modal etc. By reducing the variable to it's mean value you are removing all that extra information (uncertainty) and replacing a distribution (intervals) by a single point estimate.

Comment: If you replace a missing value by some point estimate, you're also assuming the data is missing at random.  The mean value of the random variable might not equal the mean value of the data when it's missing.

Comment: @NeilG sorry to nitpick, but replacing a missing value by its mean does not directly mean assuming the data to be missing at random.  Especially since the - somewhat confusing - terminology around missing data considers 'missing at random' to be data that is missing at random **conditional on other, but known data** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data). IMO, the way data is replaced does not imply anything about the reasoning behind it. That reasoning should be made explicit and lead up to the appropriate way of handling the missing data. That said, I fully agree with Stephan's answer.

Comment: @IWS It's fine for the missingness indicators to be conditional on the observed data.  Missing at random means that the missingness indicators depend on the unobserved data.  If you replace the variable with its mean value conditional on it being observed, that might not be the same as its unconditional mean value — unless the data are missing at random.

Comment: @NeilG Don't you mean 'missing **completely** at random', when you write 'missing at random' in the final sentence of your last comment? If so, we do are in agreement, but I was just nitpicking about terminology. (see the wiki page I've put in my comment above, I've always been taught, read and used that terminology)

Comment: For reference: [Horton & Kleinman (2007, *The American Statistician*)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/000313007X172556) provide an introduction and overview on missing data and imputation, explaining the difference between "MAR" and "MCAR", which are indeed technical terms. The book-length treatment is [Little & Rubin (2002), *Statistical Analysis with Missing Data*](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471183865.html).

Comment: @IWS missing completely at random means that the missingness indicators are also independent of the observed data.  (It's not usually a realistic assumption in the real world.) I agree with you that I should have said mcar to guarantee that the means of the entire data and the observe data coincide.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to Stephan's points:

- In almost any application where you're interested in nonlinear functions of the random variable, substituting the mean will generally introduce bias and possibly contradictory results. The average velocity and average mass of a particle will generally not be consistent with average kinetic energy, because energy scales with V^2.
- The mean value may not even be a possible outcome for the random variable. If my possible outcomes are 0 "patient dies" and 1 "patient lives", it's probably not helpful to have a model that describes the patient as 0.1 "mostly dead but slightly alive".

Comment: Obligatory: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbE8E1ez97M

Comment: @Alexis but of course!

Answer (score 0):

A real life example (related to the two answers you got), in the financial markets. The price of an option is based in the probability that the price of an asset goes above (or below) a given level.

For example, the price of an option for buying an asset at a price 100 when the expected value of the asset is 80. If you substitute the random variable (the asset price) by its mean, you would get a price of zero (as you would never by at 100 an asset that costs 80). When you take into account the stochasticity of the asset (and that's the right way of doing it) you get a positive price, as there is some probability that the asset price goes above 100.